# swift optional chaining - can it fail?

Tags: swift, option-type

When running the following code:

```
a?.b?.doSomething()
```

what happens if `a` or `b` are nil? will it fail? or just continue executing the next code?

is it the same as the following C code -

```
if (a && a.b)
   doSomething()
else
  // do nothing, without failing, nor throwing exception
```

Comment: if a or b are nil, it will not `doSomething()`, because its `nil`, there is nothing to do anything

Comment: Please read the chapter [Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) in the Swift Language Guide

Comment: Your understanding is correct. If at least 1 of `a`, `b` is nil, `doSomething` will not be called.

Comment: Did you *try* what happens if a or b are nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`b` is nil, nothing is printed out:**

```
import Foundation

struct ASample {
    var b:BSample? = nil
}

struct BSample {
    func doSomething(){
        print("Hey")
    }
}

let a: ASample? = ASample()

a?.b?.doSomething()
#
```

**`b` is not nil, "Hey" is being printed out:**

```
import Foundation

struct ASample {
    var b:BSample? = BSample()
}

struct BSample {
    func doSomething(){
        print("Hey")
    }
}

let a: ASample? = ASample()

a?.b?.doSomething()
#Hey
```

**Same applies to `a`. If `a` is nil, it won't continue the execution.**

You can try it out at http://online.swiftplayground.run/ *(PS: when you try it out omit the `#` or `#Hey` as they are only to show you what will be printed in the console).*

Answer (score 1):

Basically optional chaining used to prevent the crash in the App.
Here if you use ? it will check whether particular object is nil or not and if it is nil then it simply will not execute the method.
In case if you do not use optional, and try to execute method on nil object it will crash the app. 
So here if and only if a and b objects are non nil, doSomething() will execute.

Answer (score 1):

Also, please note that:

```
struct A {
    let b: Int? = nil
    func doSomething() { print("Doing Something") }
    func doSomethingElse() { print("Doing Something Else") }
}
let a = A()
if (a && a.b) {
    a.doSomething()
} else {
    a.doSomethingElse()
}
```

will not compile. The compiler tells you:

> Cannot convert value of type 'A' to expected value 'Bool'

In Swift, unlike, for example, C, conditionals require boolean arguments. Neither 
"a" nor "a.b" is boolean.

If you change the example to:

```
if (a != nil && a.b != nil) {
    a.doSomething()
} else {
    a.doSomethingElse()
}
```

it compiles with the warning:

> Comparing non-optional value of type 'A' to 'nil' always returns true

I didn't make "a" optional just to keep things reasonable. If you make "a" optional, then you'll get a whole lot of compile errors telling you it must be unwrapped.

Also: read the section on "guard."

IMO, optionals are a useful, and easily misused, feature of Swift.

Playground and the manual are your friends.